# Create shared row in table split into columns

Tags: tables, multicolumn

How do I add a row across multiple columns such as the "maxpool" rows below?

[image]

Comment: `\multicolumn{6}{c}{text}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use \multicolumn{no of columns to merge}{where the text should be written like centered, left or right aligned}{text} for writing "maxpool" in the row like above.

```
\multicolumn{6}{c}{text}
```

is apt for the above table.